# Converting string to number?

Tags: python

I should get this converted to numbers with `float()`.
How can I do it?

Here is the code I have problems with. It´s simplified to the problem

```
poly = input().split()
poly.reverse()
return poly
```

Comment: you said it, it's `float()` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply as you said in your question...you can use `float`:

```
>>> string = "1234.567"
>>> float(string)
1234.567
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to a number in Python with the `int()`, `float()` and `long()` built-in functions.

E.g.

```
return int(poly)
```

See the Python docs for details:

- [int()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)
- [float()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)
- [long()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#long)

Answer (score 0):

If poly is a list of strings you want to convert in floats, do:

```
floats = [float(s) for s in poly]
```